# Modify single value in pandas DataFrame with integer row and label column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to modify a single value in a DataFrame. The typical suggestion for doing this is to use `df.at[]` and reference the position as the index label and the column label, or to use `df.iat[]` and reference the position as the integer row and the integer column. But I want to reference the position as the integer row and the column label.

Assume this DataFrame:

| dateindex | apples | oranges | bananas |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 14:00:01.384624 | 1 | X | 3 |
| 2021-01-05 13:43:26.203773 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 2021-01-31 08:23:29.837238 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| 2021-02-08 10:23:09.095632 | 0 | 1 | 2 |

```
data = [{'apples':1, 'oranges':'X', 'bananas':3},
        {'apples':4, 'oranges':5,   'bananas':6},
        {'apples':7, 'oranges':8,   'bananas':9},
        {'apples':0, 'oranges':1,   'bananas':2}]
indexes = [pd.to_datetime('2021-01-01 14:00:01.384624'),
           pd.to_datetime('2021-01-05 13:43:26.203773'),
           pd.to_datetime('2021-01-31 08:23:29.837238'),
           pd.to_datetime('2021-02-08 10:23:09.095632')]
idx = pd.Index(indexes, name='dateindex')
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=idx)
```

I want to change the value "X" to "2". I don't know the exact time; I just know that it's the first row. But I do know that I want to change the "oranges" column.

I want to do something like `df.at[0,'oranges']`, but I can't do that; I get a `KeyError`.

The best thing that I can figure out is to do `df.at[df.index[0],'oranges']`, but that seems so awkward when they've gone out of their way to provide both by-label and by-integer-offset interfaces. *Is* that the best thing?

Answer (score 3):

Wrt

> The best thing that I can figure out is to do `df.at[df.index[0],'oranges']`, but that seems so awkward when they've gone out of their way to provide both by-label and by-integer-offset interfaces. *Is* that the best thing?

Yes, it is. And I agree, it is awkward. [The old `.ix`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html) used to support these mixed indexing cases better but its behaviour depended on the dtype of the axis, making it inconsistent. In the meanwhile...

The other options, which have been used in the other answers, *can* all issue the `SettingWithCopy` warning. It's not guaranteed to raise the issue but it might, based on what the indexing criteria are and how values are assigned.

Referencing [Combining positional and label-based indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#combining-positional-and-label-based-indexing) and starting with this df, which has `dateindex` as the index:

```
                             apples oranges  bananas
dateindex
2021-01-01 14:00:01.384624        1      X         3
2021-01-05 13:43:26.203773        4      5         6
2021-01-31 08:23:29.837238        7      8         9
2021-02-08 10:23:09.095632        0      1         2
```

Using both options:

1. with `.loc` or `.at`:

   ```py
   df.at[df.index[0], 'oranges'] = -50
   ```

   ```
                                apples oranges  bananas
   dateindex
   2021-01-01 14:00:01.384624        1     -50        3
   2021-01-05 13:43:26.203773        4      5         6
   2021-01-31 08:23:29.837238        7      8         9
   2021-02-08 10:23:09.095632        0      1         2
   ```
2. with `.iloc` or `.iat`:

   ```py
   df.iat[0, df.columns.get_loc('oranges')] = -20
   ```

   ```
                                apples oranges  bananas
   dateindex
   2021-01-01 14:00:01.384624        1     -20        3
   2021-01-05 13:43:26.203773        4      5         6
   2021-01-31 08:23:29.837238        7      8         9
   2021-02-08 10:23:09.095632        0      1         2
   ```

FWIW, I find approach #1 more consistent since it can handle multiple row indexes without changing the functions/methods used: `df.loc[df.index[[0, 2]], 'oranges']` but approach #2 needs a different column indexer when there are multiple columns: `df.iloc[[0, 2], df.columns.get_indexer(['oranges', 'bananas'])]`.

Comment: D.L's answer issued the warning, but changed the DataFrame in-place anyway. Whole Brain's answer did not generate the warning at all. Are you saying that it's possible for that method to fail even if it doesn't generate the warning?

Comment: @wfaulk It could generate the warning even if it _has_ changed the data correctly. Hence 'Warning' rather than 'Error'. These can be changed to errors with `pd.set_option('mode.chained_assignment','raise')`. The scenario is explained in the section [Why does assignment fail when using chained indexing?](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing). To quote a line from that page: _"The following can work at times, but it is not guaranteed to, and therefore should be avoided:"_ `dfd['a'][2] = 111`.

Comment: I guess my question is if it's possible for the problem to occur without the warning. Like, is there a scenario where the same reference style will work fine and not generate a warning with one set of data, but may still fail with another set of data? Asked another way, can I assume that if I don't get the warning that I will never get the warning in the same code path, regardless of the data? If not, is this method the only way to ensure that assignments will always work? (I'm asking specifically about the `df['oranges'].iat[0] = 2` answer provided by @whole-brain.)

Answer (score 1):

## Solution with Series.iat

If it doesn't seem more awkward to you, you can use the [`iat` method of pandas Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.1.4/reference/api/pandas.Series.iat.html):

```
df["oranges"].iat[0] = 2
```

## Time performance comparison with other methods

As this method doesn't raise any warning, it can be interesting to compare its time performance with other proposed solutions.

```
%%timeit
df.at[df.index[0], 'oranges'] = 2
# > 9.91 µs ± 47.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%%timeit
df.iat[0, df.columns.get_loc('oranges')] = 2
# > 13.5 µs ± 74.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%%timeit
df["oranges"].iat[0] = 2
# > 3.49 µs ± 16.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

The pandas.Series.iat method seems to be the most performant one (I took the median of three runs).

Let's try again with huge DataFrames

### With a DatetimeIndex

```
# Generating random data
df_large = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 50, (100000, 100000)))
df_large.columns = ["col_{}".format(i) for i in range(100000)]
df_large.index = pd.date_range(start=0, periods=100000)
# 2070-01-01 to 2243-10-16, a bit unrealistic

%%timeit
df_large.at[df_large.index[55555], 'col_55555'] = -2
# > 10.1 µs ± 85.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%%timeit
df_large.iat[55555, df_large.columns.get_loc('col_55555')] = -2
# > 13.2 µs ± 118 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%%timeit
df_large["col_55555"].iat[55555] = -2
# > 3.31 µs ± 19 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

### With a RangeIndex

```
# Generating random data
df_large = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 50, (100000, 100000)))
df_large.columns = ["col_{}".format(i) for i in range(100000)]

%%timeit
df_large.at[df_large.index[55555], 'col_55555'] = 2
# > 4.5 µs ± 18.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%%timeit
df_large.iat[55555, df_large.columns.get_loc('col_55555')] = 2
# > 13.5 µs ± 50.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%%timeit
df_large["col_55555"].iat[55555] = 2
# > 3.49 µs ± 20.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Since it is a simple indexing with `O(n)` complexity, the size of the array doesn't change much the results, <strike>except when it comes to the *"at + index"* ; strangely enough, it shows worst performance with small dataframes.</strike> Thanks to the author [wfaulk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/147202/wfaulk) for spotting that using a RangeIndex decreases the access time of the ***"at + index"*** method. The time performance remains higher and constant when dealing with DatetimeIndex with ***pd.Series.iat***.

Comment: I didn't consider slicing out the column first. This seems to work just fine. It feels a little tidier than having to reference the DataFrame inside the DataFrame.

Comment: Well not only is it the most straightforward in my opinion, but it seems to be the most time-efficient one, as I just tested.

Comment: You undersold yourself, actually. Your df_large has a simple RangeIndex. If you make it a DatetimeIndex, the index lookup slows things down even more; your way looks like it takes less than a third of the time.

Comment: @wfaulk  Well spotted, that explains the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You were actually quite close with your initial guess.

You would do it like this:

```
import pandas as pd

mydict = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4},
          {'a': 100, 'b': 200, 'c': 300, 'd': 400},
          {'a': 1000, 'b': 2000, 'c': 3000, 'd': 4000 }]
df = pd.DataFrame(mydict)
print(df)

# change th value of column a, row 2
df['a'][2] = 100

# print column a, row 2
print(df['a'][2])
```

There are lots of different variants such as `loc` and `iloc`, but this is one good method.

In the example we discovered that `loc` was optimal as `df[][]` throws an error:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [{'apples':1, 'oranges':'X', 'bananas':3},
        {'apples':4, 'oranges':5,   'bananas':6},
        {'apples':7, 'oranges':8,   'bananas':9},
        {'apples':0, 'oranges':1,   'bananas':2}]
indexes = [pd.to_datetime('2021-01-01 14:00:01.384624'),
           pd.to_datetime('2021-01-05 13:43:26.203773'),
           pd.to_datetime('2021-01-31 08:23:29.837238'),
           pd.to_datetime('2021-02-08 10:23:09.095632')]
idx = pd.Index(indexes, name='dateindex')
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=idx)

print(df)

df.loc['2021-01-01 14:00:01.384624','oranges'] = 10
# df['oranges'][0] = 10

print(df)
```

This works.

Comment: If I try to set a value with that method in my sample DataFrame (`df['oranges'][0] = 2`), I get the warning "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame"/"See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy". It happens to work for me, but apparently it's inconsistent.

Comment: Very interesting.  The `x` in your code throws this error. My example happened to use only numbers, so dodnt thorw the error.  (check: I replaced the `x` in your code with a number and there were no errors).

Comment: @wfaulk thanks for to comment.  Edited the answer to adjust for the more optimal solution `loc[,]`.

Comment: But I want to reference the row as an integer, not as the timestamp.

Comment: then you would use `iloc` in place of `loc` which does exactly that. The reason that `loc` was used in the example was because the dataframe index is timestamp (so that was used).

Comment: The main distinction between `loc` and `iloc` is: `loc` is label-based, which means that you have to specify rows and columns based on their row and column labels. `iloc` is integer position-based, so you have to specify rows and columns by their integer position values (0-based integer position).

Comment: But I want to reference a "cell" with an (integer,label) pattern. `loc` requires (label,label) and `iloc` requires (integer,integer).

Comment: use `loc[a,b]` where a is a lookup on `idx`. That would solve this.

Comment: That's the same as the solution in the question that I asked if it was the best way, except using (the supposedly slower) `loc` instead of `at`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `loc` method. It receives the row and column you want to change.

Changing X to 2: `df.loc[0, 'oranges'] = 2`

See: [pandas.DataFrame.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

Comment: That generates the error `TypeError: value should be a 'Timestamp' or 'NaT'. Got 'int' instead.`.